# Color calibration on Linux Mint

Tags: colors, monitors

I'm running Linux Mint 9.

I installed [Argyll](http://www.argyllcms.com/) and gnome-color-manager but neither of those have a GUI. I need to configure my monitor colors. Right now the white looks a little yellow etc. and I want to do photo editing in Gimp. How can I get my monitor ICC calibrated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is hardware calibration available for Linux, if you can find the hardware to do so.  The Sp*der 1 and 2 are allegedly supported.  The Sp*der 3 maybe.

[Here](http://www.tuqix.org/wordpress/?p=232) is an article on using the Pantone Huey (another inexpensive device that is actually supported on Linux).  The [X-Rite](http://www.xrite.com/) Eye-One Display is also supposedly supported, but can find no instructive links, though [this one is positive](http://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/openicc/2007q4/001032.html).

This topic is not simple and cannot be summarized in a single posting easily.  Here are a couple of [useful](http://jcornuz.wordpress.com/2007/11/16/spyder-the-good-and-the-ugly/) [links](http://jcornuz.wordpress.com/2007/11/18/use-colorvision-spyder-to-produce-an-icc-monitor-profile-under-argyllcms-linux/) on hardware calibration with the Sp*der and ArgyllCMS.

The Linux Photography blog also has this article on [dispcalGUI here](http://jcornuz.wordpress.com/2009/03/23/monito-calibration-the-dispcalgui-way/).