# Change color balance on Intel Graphics

Tags: linux, xorg, drivers, colors, intel-graphics

My laptop has some screen or cable problem, because of which the screen  is all pink colour.
In Windows I use my Graphic Card configuration software to change the screen colours mixing colour channels and hence changing the screen colour to a very normal colour that I can work on.

[image: Graphic card driver software I use on Windows]
Now is there a similar software that I can use on linux. I am now on linux and trying out different linux. Now I am using Mint. Can I find A software that I can use Like the one on windows.

Comment: You will certainly find a way here : http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17859/how-can-i-simply-adjust-monitor-color-temperture-in-x