# How to change saturation on Intel GPU

Tags: intel-graphics, display-settings, color-management

I'm familiar with redshift
[How can I simply adjust monitor color temperture in X?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17859/how-can-i-simply-adjust-monitor-color-temperture-in-x)

I'd like to change color saturation to somehow "fix" poor quality of HD display which has definitely lower color saturation than Eizo class displays or even regular fullHD display tends to have.

I know nVidia or AMD GPUs can modify saturation from their control panel, but I don't know if Intel has its own tools.

There is `intel-gpu-tools` but I cannot see proper utility there.

I have 12" dell latitude as my travel laptop and sometimes I'd like to manipulate and view photos using it. I have also 15" stationary work laptop which I don't want to travel with.

Answer (score 3):

I was doing some research on this lately, too. Unfortunately, as of today (07.01.2017), it seems it's not possible to manipulate saturation with Intel GPU on-board on *nix systems.

**EDIT:**

It looks like it's possible with `xf86-video-intel` driver using `xrandr` but only for TV outputs: https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/man/man4/intel.4.xhtml#heading6

Comment: Do you have any supporting links?

Comment: There's no clear yes/no answer on the internet, at least I couldn't find any. Just many unanswered topics all over the internet, like this one, eg.: [1](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/forum/graphics-power-users/set-video-color-saturation-xrandr-problem), [2](https://communities.intel.com/thread/94249), [3](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2003098), [4](http://askubuntu.com/questions/370153/how-can-i-improve-color-saturation-in-ubuntu), [5](http://askubuntu.com/questions/743704/set-digital-vibrance-or-saturation-with-intel-gma-graphics-for-ubuntu-15-04?rq=1). No answer is an answer too.